# No module named 'turtle'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

i am learning and trying to make a snake game in Python3
i am importing turtle

i am using: Linux mint 19, PyCharm, python37, python3-tk

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/buszter/PycharmProjects/untitled1/snake.py", line 2, in <module>
    import turtle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'
```

everywhere i am reading turtle should be preinstalled, but i still dont have it :(

i tried `pip install turtle` and says

```
 pip install turtle
Collecting turtle
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f0/21a42e9e424d24bdd0e509d5ed3c7dfb8f47d962d9c044dba903b0b4a26f/turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kvf9on0y/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    -------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-kvf9on0y/turtle/
```

EDIT

screenshot of settings of the project in pycharm

[image: screenshot of settings of the project in pycharm]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part)

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's kinda old topic, but I had the same problem right now on my Fedora 31. 
Reinstalling packages didn't work.
What worked was installing IDLE programming tool (that's just Python IDE for kids), which installs also tkinter module.
I think that installing just `python3-tkinter` (that's how this package is named in Fedora repo) package would work as well, because `turtle` is inside Tk module.

Comment: The name of the package can also be `python38-tkinter` or `python39-tkinter` depending on your Python version and distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install turtle library via pip, it must be in the standart library. 
`pip install turtle` installs [this 3rd party](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/) library. You can look at download file ([this](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/#files) tar.gz file) link of above library and link in the output of pip. They are same.

For the solution, I think you can just copy [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/turtle.py) and write in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the python your `Pycharm` is using is not `Python3.7`. Try opening a Python prompt and running import turtle, because it should be packaged into `python` already.

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

Comment: in terminal  I've run python3 and import turtle and it is working ... so I've turtle :) , but still not working.  I've add a screenshot to the question too :)

Comment: Then make sure the python you are using there is the same as what you use in PyCharm

Comment: Usually `turtle` module comes with `python`. I say reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot of your settings shows no PythonTurtle package.
Simply click on + and find the package named "PythonTurtle" click install package.

Answer (score 0):

An error will pop-up if the installed Python version doesn't include tkinter. Try running `sudo dnf install python3-tkinter` in the terminal (the command varies according to the OS)

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47648

Answer (score 0):

**turtle is included in the python standard library and must not be installed with pip!** Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

The turtle package from pypi.org is a http proxy written for python 2. It was last updated in 2009.

You should avoid to install the turtle package with pip. In most cases it should not install due to syntax errors in python 3

If you are still using python 2 this can break python installation, because this will replace your existing turtle standard library.

There is a request in the Pypi support tracker to remove the turtle package: https://github.com/pypi/support/issues/2771

Answer (score 0):

I think in recent updates of Fedora the pip and python is misbehaving.
The **Solution** to this error is installing *tinkter* which includes turtle.

```
 sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
```

Don't try wasting your time in re installing pip, python, setuptools, ...

Hopefully this will work for you :)